# Break out of an if statement

Tags: javascript, jshint

JSHint is telling me not to use a label on an `if` statement (it seems that labels are only for loops as far as jshint is concerned).

```
forminjection: if (options.addToForm !== false) {
  if (!(options.addToForm instanceof jQuery)) {
    options.addToForm = $(element).closest("form");
    if (options.addToForm.length === 0)
    {
      options.addToForm = false;
      break forminjection;
    }
  }
  $(element).each(function(index){
    //do stuff
  });
}
```

So I'm getting a warning on the first line above but also (naturally) on the `break` line.

**Update:** This code works as intended but is obviously not the right way to achieve the end result. How should it be refactored?

Comment: You can't do a traditional `break` out of an `if` statement that isn't inside of a loop. You can do a `return` to end the function execution. You're using the `break` as a goto. This is very risky and can create unmaintainable code.

Comment: If you're wanting to loop on something, you may be looking for a "For" or "while" loop. An if statement will not loop.

Comment: have you heard of spaghetti code? There is a good reason we don't use GOTO statements anymore.

Comment: @Ellis so what is the correct way to achieve what I'm doing here?

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: It could be [refactored in this way](http://pastebin.com/1aZvBNvk), but I agree it'd be nice to know if there's an alternative way of using the `break` functionality as intended without the warning.

Comment: @Ellis: This can be useful for providing clear code in some situations. I wouldn't call it abuse so hastily.

Comment: @squint You're right, abuse is a little too strong. This is not a good way to do this though.

Comment: Do you need `options.addToForm` for anything? What is it?

Comment: What specific warning are you getting?

Comment: @bhspencer `addToForm` is a plugin option that has a default value of `false` (i.e. don't add to form). It takes a jQuery form or `true` (in which case it finds the `closest` form and injects data into it.

Comment: W028: "Label 'forminjection' on if statement"

Comment: @JamesThorpe thanks for the suggestion, I must say although your code would pass, I don't see how it's an improvement.

Comment: There's an [open issue on jshint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1741) directly regarding this

Comment: @JamesThorpe thanks, I saw the issue but the point is that the coding style is bad hence the question.

Comment: *"This code works as intended but is obviously not the right way to achieve the end result. How should it be refactored?"* It doesn't need to be refactored. Don't let nonsense claims of *"spaghetti code"* and *"GOTO"* sway you.

Comment: If you really want to refactor, you can remove the `.each()` from the `if`, put it in its own `if` and in the first one, set a variable instead that'll be the condition of the second. But in more complex situations, using `break` can really add clarity to the code.

Comment: @squint there was quite strong opinion here so thanks for the vote of confidence. I had the same idea with the `each` (see below).

Comment: To be honest, at this point I think the question is just _how should I write this code so it doesn't use a break on a label and still looks "nice"_ and has become somewhat opinion based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm testing this cleaned up solution

```
if (options.addToForm instanceof jQuery || options.addToForm === true) {
  if (options.addToForm === true) {
    options.addToForm = $(element).closest("form");
  }
  if (options.addToForm.length === 0) {
    // No form found
    options.addToForm = false;
  }
}
if (options.addToForm !== false) {
  $(element).each(function(index) {
    // Do Stuff
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding the first `if` statement. In the original, you'd only pass if `addToForm` was *not* a jQuery object. Now you're doing the opposite. I wonder if in the original version you closed the second `if` in the wrong spot. Your new version makes more sense I guess.

Comment: `addToForm` could be a boolean or a jQuery object. If it's a boolean, I need to find the `closest` form but if in the end there are no elements, I can't inject. The difference is that my original code assumes that an object passed in is a form and doesn't check its length.

Comment: Yeah, that was the weird thing, that the `.length` was only checked a jQuery object had not been passed in. Now you're checking in both cases. I'd probably use separate properties for booleans and jQuery objects, but that's me. I prefer static type systems, so I'm biased. ;-)

Comment: @squint I hear you but I feel like this is the power of js and the fact that it's not strongly typed should be used and exploited rather than overlooked. I've done plenty in Java and some cpp so strongly typed systems have their appeal to me but if you have weak typing, may as well use it for what it's there for in my mind.